# Lightroom to show images of particular resolution

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog

How do I use Lightroom's library module to show me pictures with a resolution larger than 5,000 x 2,300 px in my catalog?

Comment: Technically that's "size" not "resolution".  Resolution is meaningful only in the context of rendering at a specific physical dimension, i.e. in a print or on a screen.

Comment: Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

There is presently no metadata filter in Lightroom that looks at image dimensions.  Below is what is currently available.  `Aspect Ratio` only considers the relation between vertical and horizontal size to determine Landscape vs Portrait.

[image]

If you have to have it in LR, you will probably have to submit an enhancement request to Adobe, and wait several years.

However, if you can use the command line and ImageMagick it is trivial to extract image size, which can then be used in a shell script to segregate images:

```
identify -format "%w %h" filename.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find your answer in aftermarket plugins. Jeffrey Friedl has been writing plugins for a long time, and has one called a [Data Explorer](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer) which may be worth a try. It lets you filter based on almost anything you can imagine that is in the metadata, including the pixel dimensions either post-crop or pre-crop (it is worth noting your question does not specify which is of interest, the camera's original dimension (which is closer to a "resolution" of sorts) or the resulting image after post processing and cropping, but this plugin does both). That plugin has a free period so you can determine if it works for you (after which you must make a donation for full functionality, but as of this writing the donation can be as small or large as you like).

There are a lot of plugins from a lot of authors floating around out there which may offer alternatives if this does not suit.  Search for "Lightroom plugin metadata" or variations on that.